# Uninstall Steam Beta on Ubuntu 12

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, steam, beta

I uninstalled steam beta via `sudo apt-get remove steam`, but it doesn't remove ~/.steam and ~/.local/Steam where most of the files are. Is the Uninstaller corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `apt-get remove <package>`, it only removes the package itself, not the data files created by the application. apt-get never removes config/data files from users' home directories, so you'll have to delete these manually. `sudo apt-get purge steam` removes all general config files, if they exist (usually in `/etc` or `/var/lib`).

As an example, let's think about a server running MySQL and creating huge databases. Now, if I want to switch from MySQL to Percona Server, I don't want my databases to be removed when I run `apt-get remove mysql-server && apt-get install percona-server`, but instead I want the server itself replaced with the new package.

The same could be said for desktop tools such as Picasa if that's more easily approachable. You wouldn't want to lose your photo library when you remove the application itself, would you?

Comment: So which command is necessary here? `apt-get remove steam --purge`?

Comment: Found that: [how do I get apt-get to completely uninstall a package?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-completely-uninstall-a-package-237772/)

Comment: @Onik, I think your comment should be included in the answer...